# Use parser.parse_args() with nargs and args rather than command line input

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I have an `argparse` argument `example` that accepts a variable number of strings:

```
parser.add_argument('--example', nargs='*', required=False, default='')
```

This works fine when using the CLI as usual with command-line input: `script.py --example ab cd`.

I also want this to work with arguments that are passed to `parser.parse_args(args)` [through the `args` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#args) from within the program code.

But when I try to pass `parser.parse_args(["--example", "ab cd"])`, it's interpreted as single string `"ab cd"` and not as a list of `ab` and `cd`.

Similarly, passing `parser.parse_args(["--example", "ab", "cd"])` is somehow interpreted as single argument, which is a list. So, when accessing `args.example[0]` I get the list and `args.example[1]` gets me an error.

Comment: Your `add_argument` defines a `--image_types`, but the test examples use `--example`.  I'd prefer to see a print of the actual `args` Namespace, rather than your interpretation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your link shows, you can give `parse_args` a list of strings.

```
In [210]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [211]: parser.add_argument('-i','--image_types', nargs='*', default='');
```

To test parsing without any commandline arguments, by giving it an empty list:

```
In [212]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[212]: Namespace(image_types='')
```

With a list of strings:

```
In [213]: parser.parse_args(['-i','a','b'])
Out[213]: Namespace(image_types=['a', 'b'])
```

or split a string:

```
In [214]: parser.parse_args('-i a b'.split())
Out[214]: Namespace(image_types=['a', 'b'])
```

Answers to `argparse` questions often use one of these forms to illustrate their actions.  The `split` is convenient.

It is also possible to create an `args` Namespace directly:

```
In [215]: argparse.Namespace(image_types=['a','b','c'])
Out[215]: Namespace(image_types=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

---

I don't follow your interpretation of the result for

```
parser.parse_args(["--example", "ab", "cd"])
```

That should produce a `args.example` that is `["ab", "cd"]`.

This isn't a good test case:

```
parser.parse_args(["--example", "ab cd"])
```

to produce the same thing from the commandline you'd have to use

```
python --example "ab cd"
```

The quotes override the normal split on white space.  You have to use `shlex.split` to emulate that behavior.

Comment: Thanks your answer helped my debug my program and fix the error. It was actually not inside `argparse` but already before. I didn't pass the arguments to `parser.parse_args` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is tricky for argparse to handle lists directly use a csv list instead:

```
parser.add_argument('--image_types', \
  help='csv list of imagetypes', \
  default='iff,gif,jpeg,png', default=None)

if args.image_types:
  args.image_types = args.image_types.split(',')
```

Comment: Seems a bit like a hack, but I guess I'll fall back to this if there's no easier/more elegant option.